# How to find and draw the Bayes decision boundary in LDA (2 classes)?

Tags: linear, discriminant-analysis

Can anyone point me (or even show me if that's allowed here) how to calculate and draw the boundary line in LDA when we have only 2 classes? In the example I'm trying to do (in a paper), the informations given to us are the following:

**Prior probabilities**
$$π_1 = 0.7$$
$$π_2 = 0.3$$
**Mean vectors**
$$μ_1 = \binom{0}{4}$$
$$μ_2 = \binom{2}{2}$$
**Covariance matrix**
$$Σ = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0.25\\
  0.25 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The question was asked and answered, especially about 2-class case, a few times on this site. Did you try to search?

Comment: I did and I didn't find what I was looking for, if you can show me these answers I would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Main idea:

Let $y \in \{1,2\}$ be the output, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be the input. Using Bayes' theorem:

1. $p(y=1 \mid x) = \frac{p(x \mid y=1)\pi_1}{p(x)}$
2. $p(y=2 \mid x) = \frac{p(x \mid y=2)\pi_2}{p(x)}$.

Plugging in a two-dimensional input $x$ into these formulas, you will get the probability of ending up with the conditional probability that $y=1$ or $y=2$. The decision boundary is the line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where these two conditional probabilities are equal. To find this line, solve $p(y=1 \mid x) = p(y=2 \mid x)$ or
$$
p(x \mid y=1)\pi_1 = p(x \mid y=2)\pi_2.
$$
Taking it a little further:
\begin{align*}
.7  \exp\left(-.5[x - \mu_1]^T\Sigma^{-1}[x - \mu_1] \right) - .3  \exp\left(-.5[x - \mu_2]^T\Sigma^{-1}[x - \mu_2] \right)&= 0  \\
\exp\left(-.5\left\{-2x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 + 2 x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_2 + \mu_1^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 - \mu_2^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_2 \right\} \right) &= \frac{3}{7} \\
-2x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 + 2 x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_2 + \mu_1^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 - \mu_2^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_2 &= 1.69\\
x^T\left[2\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right]+ \left\{\mu_1^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 - \mu_2^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu_2\right\} &= 1.69.
\end{align*}

Assuming both classes have the same $\Sigma$ comes in handy a few times. You can see how it starts to look linear (in $x$). Hence the "L" in LDA.

Comment: Would it be bad manners for me to ask you to help me solve that equation?

Comment: @Haitam no, that's fine; I'll take it a litte further